# How does TCP knows the correct order of data?

Tags: tcp

TCP will re-order the data if they arrived in the wrong order, but how does TCP knows the correct order of data, does TCP knows the correct order of data by looking at the sequence numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*does TCP knows the correct order of data by looking at the sequence numbers?*"

Yes, that is one thing the sequence numbers are for.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important features of transport layer protocols is to segment the message. This is called segmentation. Each segment is given a sequence number and transmitted.  TCP knows the correct order of data by sequence number. This is answer the question.
But what if one of the segments is not transmitted to the receiver? With the ACK number feature, TCP will notify the sending party of the non-transmitted segment and provide retransmission.

Comment: "TCP will notify the sending party of the non-transmitted segment" - only when the *fast retransmit* feature is in use and duplicate ACKs are sent by the receiver. Basic TCP waits for the segment timer to run out and then retransmits.